# Berkshelf: upload a wrapper cookbook and its dependencies to Chef Server simultaneously

Tags: chef-infra, berkshelf

I've made a simple wrapper cookbook for the community `vim` cookbook. It's called `ws-vim`. I wanted to upload it to my hosted Chef Server so I ran `$ berks upload ws-vim` from the cookbook directory where the `Berksfile` and `Berksfile.lock` are. This only uploaded my wrapper cookbook and when I viewed a role in the Chef Server that mentioned this cookbook it said the role couldn't be used because I was missing the `vim` dependency. Sure enough it hadn't been uploaded when I did the `berks` command.

I was under the impression that this would upload my wrapper cookbook *and* its dependencies as specified in `Berksfile.lock` all at the same time, similar to how `$ berks install` installs all my dependencies and my dependencies' dependencies at the same time.

Berks is great but what if I have a huge dependency tree? Do I really have to upload each cookbook to my Chef Server manually? Surely I'm missing something but I couldn't find anything in the docs/Google to help. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than `berks upload ws-vim` you just want to run `berks upload` (or maybe something like `berks upload -e test` if you're using the groups feature) from inside the `ws-vim` folder. This will do the full recursive upload for you. By passing a specific name you told it to upload *only* that cookbook and ignore dependencies. This can be useful in some cases (hotfix pushes, etc), but not usually what you want.